# Kiwi-Tcms integration quesrtion on jira

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I try to integrate jira on kiwi, when I click report bug and choice jira, then I open chrome developer tool to check message , I get 504 Gateway Timeout, so... I want to ask which steps I missed??

My step like this:

1. build kiwi-tcms on macOS Catalina v10.15.5
2. change site Domain name : 192.168.50.110
3. go on bug tracker to set jira

```
    Tracker type: jira
    
    Base URL: https://jirausername.atlassian.net/browse/KIWI-1

    API URL: "empty"

    API username: jirausername

    API password: jirauserpassword
```

4. report bug

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

504 Gateway Timeout on the Jira side is nothing we can do about. You have to contact Atlassian support and talk to them.

A 504 on the Kiwi TCMS backend side would probably point to a slow DB or slow network error but we need more information about that:

- Is the 504 on the Kiwi TCMS side or on the JIRA side ?
- If on the Kiwi TCMS side which HTTP request exactly is triggering the timeout?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think maybe my kiwi environment needs to be connected to the external network.